# What Module to include for ActiveQt?

Tags: qt, activex, qmake, activeqt

What Module do I include in `.pro` file for using Active Qt? I mean `QT += ?`. 
And: Can I develop Commercial Software using ActiveQt? (I am using Qt LGPL).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt/QMake isn't always consistent in how to include its modules in `.pro` files. In this case (as with `CONFIG+=designer`), it's

```
CONFIG += axserver    # for an ActiveX server component
CONFIG += axcontainer # for an ActiveX client
```

Cf.  http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/activeqt-server.html.

As for licensing, you should of course always consult a lawyer when you're in doubt.

That said, the common interpretation seems to be that you can use the ActiveQt framework in proprietary projects, yes, due to their BSD license (documented for [`QAxContainer` here](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qaxcontainer.html#license-information) and for [`QAxServer` here](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qaxserver.html#license-information)). You should also be able to link these modules in statically (which is not possible with the LGPL'ed Qt modules), however, you should note the clause that requires binary distributions to include a particular disclaimer...

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 modules for ActiveX : [QAxServer](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qaxserver.html) and [QAxContainer](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qaxcontainer.html). They are both licensed under BSD License as it says in the doc.

To include those modules i beleive you have to use

```
QT += qaxserver qaxcontainer
```